# Working with Sheets in DELPHI - ActiveCell.Column returning wrong value

Tags: excel, delphi

i want to get the number of rows and columns from a excel sheet.
I'm currently using this code:

```
function TFprofiles.XlsToStringGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid; AXLSFile: string): Boolean;
const
    xlCellTypeLastCell = $0000000B;
var
    XLApp, Sheet: OLEVariant;
    RangeMatrix: Variant;
    x, y, k, r: Integer;            
begin
  Result:=False; 
  XLApp:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
try     

    XLApp.Visible:=False;
    XLApp.Workbooks.Open(AXLSFile);

    Sheet := XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)].WorkSheets[1];

    Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Select;

    y := XLApp.ActiveCell.Row;

    x := XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;

    AGrid.RowCount:=24;
    AGrid.ColCount:=x;     

    RangeMatrix := XLApp.Range['B2', XLApp.Cells.Item[y,x]];
    RangeMatrix := RangeMatrix.Value;

    (...)

end;
```

Everything works fine except for this line:

```
 x := XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;;
```

My worksheet has **2 COLUMNS** and ActiveCell.Column returns me 5,9, or any other value except 2!!!
I selected and deleted all the values from other cells/columns

What's possibly the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Why should `ActiveCell.Row` be bound to number of columns? You do know difference between rows and columns?

Comment: If your *worksheet has **2 COLUMNS** * then why are you expecting a **2** when asking for *ActiveCell. **Row** *?

Comment: Sorry, this line " x := XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;" hahahaha
I edited the question

Comment: hahahaha. Use `x := Sheet.ActiveCell.Column;`

Comment: It gives me this error "Method ActiveCell not supported by automation object" =/

Comment: `ActiveCell` works correctly, the error is in your expectation

Answer (score 1):

You define *Sheet* as the first worksheet in the workbook then decide somewhat arbitrarily whenever to bother using it or not.

```
Sheet := XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)].WorkSheets[1];

y := Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Row;
x := Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Column;

...     

RangeMatrix := Sheet.Range['B2', Sheet.Cells.Item[y,x]];
```

I've replaced a few occurrences of `xlApp` with `Sheet` while trying to avoid the use of `.Select`. If this isn't perfect, it is because I do not have Delphi but you should get the general idea.

Comment: btw, `xlCellTypeLastCell` is equal to **11** if you need to replace it with its numerical constant (which may not be defined in Delphi).

Answer (score 0):

I find that instead of messing around with “…SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell…”.

It is easier to use “UsedRange” like this >>

```
x := Sheet.UsedRange.Row + Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;
y := Sheet.UsedRange.Column + Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1;
```

Problem with SpecialCells is that you can't use it on a Protected Sheet.